# How can I get SUM values for each rows on SELECT without go twice in the table and without use 'WITH' clause?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I need get the total SUM for each rows in my query, but I don't want go twice in the table.

I tried do this:

```
SELECT id, value, SUM(value) as total FROM product
```

But my result was this:

```
id  value  total
3    30     60
```

---

If I do the bellow query I get my wanted result, but I need go twice in the table:

```
SELECT id, value, (SELECT SUM(value) FROM product) as total FROM product
```

Or if I use 'WITH' clause, but this is not supported before Android 5:

```
WITH data AS (SELECT id, value FROM product) 
    SELECT id, value, (SELECT SUM(value) FROM data) as total FROM data
```

Wanted result:

```
id  value  total
1    10     60
2    20     60
3    30     60
```

Thank you!

Comment: I'd imagine not the solution, but my first guess if you want it to eval only once, create a variable that is sum(value) and then select id, value, @variable (@variable being the notation it would be in SQL Server, not sure on SQLite, sorry)

Comment: Another, perhaps more backwards-compatible way of writing this in a way that keeps it more readable than nesting SELECT statements might be using a crossjoin like so:


`SELECT A.id, A.value, B.total


FROM product AS A, 


(SELECT SUM(value) AS Total FROM product) AS B`

Comment: @Robert Unfortunately it's not possible using SQLite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible using your SQLite version. You'll have to use two selects.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have to use a subquery.

However, perhaps you may be less concerned about the 2nd table as I believe that the Query Planner will determine that it only needs to calculate the sum once and does away with the need for a variable as it stores the value in cache.

I believe that the results of using `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN your_query` shows this. i.e. using

```
EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT id, value, (SELECT sum(value) FROM products) AS total FROM products;
```

results in :-

[image]

This being explained as (***see bolded statements***) :-

> #### 1.3. Subqueries
>
> In all the examples above, the first column (column "selectid") is
>   always set to 0. If a query contains sub-selects, either as part of
>   the FROM clause or as part of SQL expressions, then the output of
>   EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN also includes a report for each sub-select. Each
>   sub-select is assigned a distinct, non-zero "selectid" value. The
>   top-level SELECT statement is always assigned the selectid value 0.
>   For example:
>
> ```
> sqlite> EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT (SELECT b FROM t1 WHERE a=0), (SELECT a FROM t1 WHERE b=t2.c) FROM t2;
> 0|0|0|SCAN TABLE t2
> 0|0|0|EXECUTE SCALAR SUBQUERY 1
> 1|0|0|SEARCH TABLE t1 USING COVERING INDEX i2 (a=?)
> 0|0|0|EXECUTE CORRELATED SCALAR SUBQUERY 2
> 2|0|0|SEARCH TABLE t1 USING INDEX i3 (b=?)
> ```
>
> The example above contains a pair of scalar subqueries assigned
>   selectid values 1 and 2. As well as a SCAN record, there are also 2
>   "EXECUTE" records associated with the top level subquery (selectid 0),
>   indicating that subqueries 1 and 2 are executed by the top level query
>   in a scalar context. The CORRELATED qualifier present in the EXECUTE
>   record associated with scalar subquery 2 indicates that the query must
>   be run separately for each row visited by the top level query. **Its
>   absence in the record associated with subquery 1 means that the
>   subquery is only run once and the result cached.** In other words,
>   subquery 2 may be more performance critical, as it may be run many
>   times whereas **subquery 1 is only ever run once**.
>
> Unless the flattening optimization is applied, if a subquery appears
>   in the FROM clause of a SELECT statement, SQLite executes the subquery
>   and stores the results in a temporary table. It then uses the contents
>   of the temporary table in place of the subquery to execute the parent
>   query. This is shown in the output of EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN by
>   substituting a "SCAN SUBQUERY" record for the "SCAN TABLE" record that
>   normally appears for each element in the FROM clause. For example:
>
> ```
> sqlite> EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT count(*) FROM (SELECT max(b) AS x FROM t1 GROUP BY a) GROUP BY x;
> 1|0|0|SCAN TABLE t1 USING COVERING INDEX i2
> 0|0|0|SCAN SUBQUERY 1
> 0|0|0|USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY
> ```
>
> If the flattening optimization is used on a subquery in the FROM
>   clause of a SELECT statement, then the output of EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN
>   reflects this. For example, in the following there is no "SCAN
>   SUBQUERY" record even though there is a subquery in the FROM clause of
>   the top level SELECT. Instead, since the flattening optimization does
>   apply in this case, the EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN report shows that the top
>   level query is implemented using a nested loop join of tables t1 and
>   t2.
>
> ```
> sqlite> EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM t2 WHERE c=1), t1;
> 0|0|0|SEARCH TABLE t2 USING INDEX i4 (c=?)
> 0|1|1|SCAN TABLE t1
> ```

[EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](https://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html)

#### End Note

Perhaps of relevance is this statement :-

> The best feature of SQL (in all its implementations, not just SQLite)
>   is that it is a declarative language, not a procedural language. When
>   programming in SQL you tell the system what you want to compute, not
>   how to compute it. The task of figuring out the how is delegated to
>   the query planner subsystem within the SQL database engine.

[Query Planning](https://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html)

You may also find this of interest [he SQLite Query Optimizer Overview](https://sqlite.org/optoverview.html) noting that as of release 3.8.0 [The Next-Generation Query Planner](https://sqlite.org/queryplanner-ng.html) is utilised.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I know that subquery will run once. However I need go just once on the table.

Comment: It would appear that the only option to meet your need would be [Custom Builds Of SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/custombuild.html)

Comment: uhhm funny that the official SQL documentation states *One solution is to bundle the SQLite library directly into the application, bypassing the version built-in to Android. This project, the SQLite Android bindings, provides an easy way to do just that. This allows an application to use a custom build or version of SQLite, regardless of the Android version to which it is deployed, while continuing to use the standard Android interface.* [SQLite Android Bindings](https://sqlite.org/android/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki)

Comment: Not that I've used it there also appears to be **SquiDB** [Using a custom SQLite build](https://github.com/yahoo/squidb/wiki/Using-a-custom-SQLite-build)